# Uploading a "LOCAL" file from nodejs to rails graphql backend (server to server)

Tags: node.js, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, apollo-upload-client

## This is not about "client to server" upload.

I am looking for a way to upload a file from **nodejs server to rails backend graphql server (server to server).**
The rails backend is working fine, and it can take file uploads without a problem if it was from a client.

The problem I am having is to create/build a ["File" object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) in nodejs, so that I can use an Apollo mutation like this to upload the file.

```js
// nodejs server side, NOT react client side
const { data } = await client.mutate<
FileUploadMutation,
FileUploadMutationVariables
>({
  mutation: FileUploadDocument,
  variables: {
    input: {
      file: file // how do I create this file object from a local file?
    },
  }
})
```

If it was the client side, it's very simple.

```jsx
<input type="file" onchange={(event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0]  // this can be the "file" object
}}/>
```

Is it possible to create an equivalent file object as [the client side File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) in nodejs?

```js
import fs from "fs"

// giving this "file" object to the mutation doen't upload the file
const file = fs.createReadStream("./local/file/path.jpg")
```

### Things I tried

- created a new rails graphql backend with [apollo_upload_server](https://github.com/jetruby/apollo_upload_server-ruby)
- created a new nextjs
- [posting a file working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrpJa.png) on the server-end ([Altair GraphQL Client](https://altair.sirmuel.design/))

  - I see the file as `<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f9e1ac0e8a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20211020-14-156qwls.jpg ...`
- created a Blob object, but I get this error `Variable $input of type TestMutationInput! was provided invalid value for file ({} is not a valid upload)` on the front-end

#### package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "generate": "graphql-codegen -w --config codegen.yml"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.16",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^16.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.6.1",
    "next": "^11.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.2.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.2.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.1.8",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.1.6",
    "@types/apollo-upload-client": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.30",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

#### (nextjs)/api/test.ts (nodejs)

```tsx
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client"
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client"
import { Blob } from "buffer"
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
// import { Blob } from "node:buffer"
import * as Generated from "src/generated/graphql"

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: createUploadLink({
    uri: "http://backend:3000/graphql",
  }),
})

// checking if the apollo connection is good at all ------------
client
  .query<Generated.TestFieldQuery, Generated.TestFieldQueryVariables>({
    query: Generated.TestFieldDocument,
    variables: {},
  })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    // this actually returns data
    console.log("data:", data)
  })
// checking if the apollo connection is good at all ------------


export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  // const buffer = fs.readFileSync(fs.realpathSync("./test.jpg"))
  // const file = new Blob([buffer], { type: "image/jpg" })
  const file = new Blob(["abc123"], { type: "text/plain" })
  console.log("file:", file)

// this mutation gives me this error
//   graphQLErrors: [
//    {
//      message: 'Variable $input of type TestMutationInput! was provided invalid value for file ({} is not a valid upload)',
//      locations: [Array],
//      extensions: [Object]
//    }
//  ],
  await client.mutate<
    Generated.TestMutationMutation,
    Generated.TestMutationMutationVariables
  >({
    mutation: Generated.TestMutationDocument,
    variables: {
      input: {
        file,
      },
    },
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  })

  res.status(200).end()
}
```

Comment: GraphQL does not support file uploads and not even Apollo comes with [this](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client) out of the box. In what format does that rails backend expect files? And what would you do with the `file` if you were in a browser?

Comment: "*This is not about "client to server" upload.*" - sure is, as all HTTP is, it's just that you have a node.js client not a browswer client. That's why you are still using the Apollo *client* library.

Comment: As matter of fact, I am using jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client v12.1.0 on the client-side.   So like I said, the rails backend can receive file uploads fine.

Comment: "client" I mean more like "browser".  No offence, but, yes I am using Apollo client, so it's "client to server" if you take it literally.  But I am more like focusing on how to create a "File object" like the client (browser) can in nodejs.

Comment: Ah, so the rails server expects a multipart upload according to the Apollo spec? You could just hand-craft that. Also, have you seen https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/134, https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/32 and https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/129?

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/172#issuecomment-605873969

https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#blob

I guess my version was just too old... I think I can create Blob in nodejs.  I will try this tomorrow and answer to my question when it actually uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I nailed it.

https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/272

```tsx
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client"
import { createUploadLink, isExtractableFile } from "apollo-upload-client"
import FormData from "form-data"
import fs, { ReadStream } from "fs"
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import * as Generated from "src/generated/graphql"

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: createUploadLink({
    uri: "https://backend/graphql",
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#server-side-polyfills
    // nextjs already polyfills this
    // fetch: ...
    // yarn add form-data or in my case @graphql-codegen had it
    FormData,  
    isExtractableFile: (value) =>
      isExtractableFile(value) ||
      (typeof ReadStream !== "undefined" && value instanceof ReadStream),
  }),
})

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const file = fs.createReadStream(fs.realpathSync("./test.jpg"))

  await client.mutate<
    Generated.TestMutationMutation,
    Generated.TestMutationMutationVariables
  >({
    mutation: Generated.TestMutationDocument,
    variables: {
      input: {
        file,
      },
    },
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  })

  res.status(200).end()
}
```